# Can I shorten/change the name of a font in my app's menu?

Tags: fonts, interface-design

I am making an app in which users can select a font, however some of the OFL fonts I have collected have a name which doesn't fit in the font selection menu. Is it ok to shorten or change the name?

Comment: It's pretty _ofl_ if you can't. On the other hand, do you need to see the full name? I'm not sure if I've ever typed in the full name of a font to use it. Might've searched for "Arial" with the full name once or twice..

Comment: @Joonas that is true, i guess it's not a big deal if they can't see the full name

Comment: I edited the title of your question to make it more clear you're asking about changing the name of the font _in the app menu_,